# How do I choose a twisted pair shielded cable?

Tags: cables, shielding, twisted-pair

The charging/discharging of a battery (1u to 30 mA) and remote voltage measurement is to be performed over 2 pairs of 2 m cable. In order to [reduce picked up common mode noise](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265613/the-best-way-to-get-rid-off-common-mode-noise-for-remote-measurement) I intend to use shielded twisted pair cable.

But I don't know which one to choose. There are several properties to consider.

The first is the gauge. This one is clear: the thicker, the better.

Somewhat more obscure are the types that listed i. e on [Mouser](http://www.mouser.de/Wire-Cable/Multi-Conductor-Paired-Cables/Multi-Conductor-Cables/_/N-9ms9i?P=1yotsiyZ1z0t1rp): what is the real difference beetween those types?

Then there is insulation and jacket material. I am not sure whether I need to consider it in the first place?

And the last and most difficult is the shield itself.

I know that there are braided shield, which has lower resistance, and foil which has better coverage. But I can't decide what of that is more important (?)

Is there perhaps something else that has to be taken in account?

I would like to get anwsers disregarding whether you think I need shielding or not.

EDIT:
this what I see if I attach oscilloscope probe to a 1.8 m unconnected unshielded cable:

Full signal:[image]

Bandlimited to see low frequency more clearly:
[image]

First picture zoomed in time:
[image]

Comment: Does the cable really matter for your signal bandwidth? Like the probes for those 6 1/2 digit multimeters uses neither shielded nor twisted cable for the probes and there's no problem of that ever. Are you sure the cable is the the bottleneck of your performance? Your application is not like hi-fi where $$ cable sounds better than $ cable, is it?

Comment: This is precise DC measurement, so the bandwidth is ideally 0. So I try limit external disturbance as much as possible.

Comment: Whatever noise your cables will pick will necessarily be AC. Unless you're going to do 50 measurements per second, you'll hardly benefit from shielding.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev. In fact, I will. perhaps up to 100 per second

Comment: @AndreyPro Then I suggest you get shielded cables for mains-powered appliances near your setup. Shields are much more effective when placed near the source.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev. I can't shield power lines. Ok, forget  about what I wrote about application. I still want to get the answers.

Comment: The quality of the shielding you'll need depends entirely on the sort of noise sources you system will encounter. If you don't know what these are, then there is no 'correct' solution. Personally I would just measure the voltage right at the terminals with a microcontroller and send the value to wherever it needs to go as a digital signal.

Comment: Added pictures to demostrate the noise. Hopefully now you can be so generous and anwser my questions.

Comment: @AndreyPro Being snarky isn't a good way to get answers...